# SQL Server 2008 R2 large polygons along latitude

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, spatial, geography

Working on the Pacific Ocean, i am dealing with huge polygons covering the whole area. Some of them are quite simple and are defined by 4 points in my shapefile.

However, when i import them into SQL server 2008 r2 as new geographies, due to the shape of the earth, i end up with curved lines while I would like the North and South boundaries to stick to some specific latitudes: for example, the north boundaries should follow the 30N latitude from 120E to 120W.

How can i force my polygons to follow the latitudes? Converting them as geometry could have been an option but since i will need to do some length and area calculations, i need to keep them as geography.
Do i need to add additional vertices along my boundaries to force the polygon to stay on a specific latitude? What should be the interval between each vertex?

Thanks for your help

Sylvain

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered this yourself.  Long distances between latitude coordinates will create curved lines to match the Earth's curvature.  Therefore if you need to "anchor" them along a specific latitude you will need to manually insert points.  As for the interval, there's no right or wrong, a little experimentation here (and considering how "anal" you want to be about it hugging the line) will give you the result you desire.  1 coordinate per degree should do it, might even be a little overkill.

That said, I do question why you would want to anchor them to create a projected "straight" line as this will skew the results of length and area calculations, the bigger the polygon, the bigger the skew.

Comment: Thanks Jon for this. Using ArcGIs, i'm using the densify tool from GeoTools to add new vertices along my Northern and Southern boundaries. I had to do so because in the case of a polygon with the following coordinates (120 30, 220 30, 220 -30, 120 -30, 120 30)  along the 30 and -30 parallels, in SQL server, checking if a specific point was falling into my polygon using STIntersects method, a point with 170 30.5 coordinates was considered as being part of the polygon while it should be outside.  Having additional vertices would force the polygons to follow the parallels. Hope it makes sense.